# AJAX JSON error

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I followed a tutorial and created RESTful webservice using Spring and deployed in tomcat. When I access the URL through browser or POSTER, it gives me the json data.
URL: `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/rest/kfc/brands/kfc-kampar`
JSON data returned is **{"name":"kfc-kampar","staffName":["mkyong1","mkyong2"]}**
And I have created a test.html page with jquery. I am making a AJAX request to get the data from the above URL and put it in a div block. javascript code is

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/rest/kfc/brands/kfc-kampar',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        dataType: "jsonP",
        success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $("#jsontest").html(data[0].name);

        },
        error: function(e, xhr){
        alert("error"+e);
        err=e;
        }
});
```

When I debug the javascript code using firebug, it always goes to error block and doesnt return me the json data. Am I missing something here? test.html is a local html file.

If I use dataType "json" , statusText returned is "[Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/general/jquery-1.8.0.min.js :: .send :: line 2" data: no]"

If I use dataType "jsonP" statusText returned is "success" but xhr returned is "parsererror"

Comment: I have added the error in question itself. Thanks

Comment: Where to add JSON.stringfy() ? execution is not at all going inside success block, it always goes to error block.

Comment: Why jsonp? Are they going to run on different domains? Does your server return a proper jsonp response? Could you post that response here?